# Custom command when pressing Power Button on GNOME 3.20

Tags: gnome, keyboard-shortcuts, power-management, gnome-shell

I'm using GNOME 3.20 (on Archlinux, with `systemd` and no `acpid`).
Since GNOME only allows three options as actions for when pressing the power button (hibernate, sleep, or nothing), i'd like to execute a custom command when the keyboard power button is pressed.

The command would be `gnome-session-quit --power-off`.

I tried to set `org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power` to `nothing` and set a custom media key (keyboard shortcut) on the keyboard power button to do so, but nothing happens when i press the button. (When i set custom media keys with keys other than PowerButton, it works).

I also tried to write a GNOME Shell Extension adding a custom key binding through the `Main.wm.addKeybinding` function, but also here, nothing happens when the key is set to PowerButton, but it works perfectly with other keys.

A solution would be to capture global keyboard events directly in the extension and not use `Main.wm.addKeybinding`, but i did not find anything to do so.

Does anyone have a solution? Preferably, not involving recompiling `gnome-settings-daemon`, because i tried that a couple times and it was too ugly.

Thanks

Comment: Unless you're willing to patch the source code, ([as I said here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/242129)) no, I don't think there's another way.