# Centos7 on NUC suspends when power button is pressed

Tags: centos, systemd, power-management, logind

Platform: Intel NUC NUC5CPYH

OS: Centos 7 with 3.10.0-327.22.2.el7.x86_64

When I press the chassis power button, the system goes in to suspend mode instead of the expected poweroff. This seems pretty simple and is the default action from logind

```
grep Power /etc/systemd/logind.conf
#HandlePowerKey=poweroff
#PowerKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
```

But when I push the power button, I see this in the logs

```
Aug  6 15:33:45 localhost systemd-logind: Power key pressed.
Aug  6 15:33:50 localhost systemd-logind: Delay lock is active (UID 1000/testuser, PID 1762/gnome-shell) but inhibitor timeout is reached.
Aug  6 15:33:50 localhost systemd: Reached target Sleep.
Aug  6 15:33:50 localhost systemd: Starting Sleep.
Aug  6 15:33:50 localhost systemd: Starting Suspend...
Aug  6 15:33:50 localhost systemd-sleep: Suspending system...
```

I've tried setting debug level logging on systemd and logind, but didn't get any more information.

Why does the "poweroff" action end up at the Sleep target?

Comment: Does a `systemctl start poweroff.target` work as expected? Does setting `HandlePowerKey=poweroff` and to `ignore` make a difference?

Comment: If your DE is Gnome 3 then this is  a duplicate of [how to set power button to shutdown instead of suspend?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/242129)

Answer (score 3):

@maxschlepzig - `systemctl start poweroff.target` sucessfully powers down the machine. I didn't try changing`HandlePowerKey=poweroff` because I was also looking at gnome settings.

@don_crissti - I was so focused on the systemd angle that I didn't even think of gnome being part of the process. You're correct, this is a duplicate questions of [Gnome 3: how to set power button to shutdown instead of suspend?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/242129/gnome-3-how-to-set-power-button-to-shutdown-instead-of-suspend/)
. The accepted answer there is to patch and rebuild `gnome-settings-daemon`.

Before attempting that patch, I looked at

`$ gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power  button-power
'suspend'`

and suspend is what it was doing, but not what I wanted. Looking at the possible values for the button-power key

`$ gsettings range org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power  button-power
enum
'blank'
'suspend'
'shutdown'
'hibernate'
'interactive'
'nothing'
'logout'`

Since shutdown is what I wanted to do, I updated that key

`gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power  button-power shutdown`

Now the power button will cleanly shutdown the machine.

Not being much of a Gnome expert, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: The only downside is to wait 60 seconds until the power off (which is, until now, not customizable).